# How to run query on date time colomn

Tags: c#, sql

Trying to retrieve records by passing date in where condition, i am sending date by using date time picker but at the end reader not showing any record.

I did conversion of date time as `Convert(char(10),ext_date,101)` still facing the same problem.

```
string str=@"select * from extra_expense where CONVERT(char(10),ext_date,101) = @date";

sqlcommand = new SqlCommand(str,sqlconnection );
sqlcommand.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value  = datetimepicker1.value);
datareader = sqlcommand.ExecuteReader();
List<Projects> projects = new List<Projects>();
while (datareader.Read())
{

     Projects proj = new Projects();
     proj.expenseid = Convert.ToInt32(datareader.GetValue(0));
     proj.ProjectDate = Convert.ToDateTime(datareader.GetValue(1));

     projects.Add(proj);

}
datareader.Close();
return projects;
```

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?  What is the value of `datetimepicker1.value`?  Is it in a SQL format?

Comment: What's the data type ext_date? -- In most cases you wouldn't need the cast, but if it is a varchar type it is most likely a globalization problem. (yyyy-MM-dd vs yyyy-dd-MM or similar).

Comment: Why are you converting `ext_date`?  Have you already checked for exact matches in the database?

Comment: data type of ext_Date id (datetime) and some records are their like 2012-03-23 11:46:35.000,2012-03-28 15:53:22.000   and datetime picker value is "23-03-12 4:36:27 PM", so it should show id of record for the same date as i think conversion is required here as i do not want to compare time value in database.

Comment: I think you need to compare by date only (ie. stripping the time)

Comment: i used it earlier and it worked, but don't know may be m lacking somewhere !!

Answer (score 1):

You can specify dates as strings in T-SQL, like so:

```
SELECT MyFields FROM MyTable
WHERE StartDate >= '01-01-00' AND StartDate <= '12-31-00'
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think this works only if the date as string matches a certain patter that may be configured in the database. So if that configuration changes, then this would not work.

Comment: In that case I believe you can use the #-syntax: WHERE StartDate >= #2000-01-01# AND StartDate <= #2000-12-31#

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't cast the field in the table, you should cast the parameter to the correct type. In fact, you are already casting it because the parameter is declared as datetime, but on your query you are forcing ext_date to char(10).
Try this:

```
string str=@"select * from extra_expense where ext_date = @date";
```

along with

```
sqlcommand.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value  = datetime.Parse( datetimepicker1.value);
```

Comment: Got it solved                                                  string str="select * from extra_expense where CONVERT(varchar(10),ext_date,101) = @date";
     
            sqlcommand.Parameters.Add("@date",SqlDbType.DateTime).Value=DateTime.Parse(date);  where date is datetimepicker1.text